# Python - how to convert and determine a type of a 5 digit date?

Tags: python, python-3.x, date, timestamp

I have some of the date fields represented as 5-digit numbers. And there is a mapping from the numbers to an actual date. However I can't figure out what logic should be applied to convert the numbers to dates in the `"%Y-%m-%d"` format?

```
13581 -> 2007-03-09
12784 -> 2005-01-01
```

Comment: They are the number of days since 1 Jan 1970.

Comment: See e.g. `datetime.utcfromtimestamp(13581 * 86400)`

Comment: In other words you want `datetime.utcfromtimestamp(n * 86400).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")` (with the input in `n`, and after `from datetime import datetime`). There may be some symbolic constant in place of the 86400 (number of seconds in a day), but it's scarcely about to change if you hard-code it!

Comment: There's also `(datetime.utcfromtimestamp(0) + timedelta(n)).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")` which avoids hard-coding the 86400. (`timedelta` is imported from `datetime` also, obviously.)

Comment: @alaniwi at this point, why not just post an answer?

Comment: @r.ook Okay, will do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The numbers shown are the numbers of days since 1st January 1970, which is the origin of Unix time.

They can be converted using for example:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
n = 13581
print((datetime.utcfromtimestamp(0) + timedelta(n)).strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
```

gives:

```
2007-03-09
```

Here `timedelta` is called with a single argument, being the offset in days.  In general it is called with `timedelta(days, seconds, microseconds)` but all of these arguments default to zero.

Comment: How can I apply this to column in a dataframe?

Answer (score 2):

As shown by

```
import datetime
datetime.date(2005, 1, 1)-datetime.timedelta(days=12784)
# datetime.date(1970, 1, 1)
```

your number is the number of days since 1970-01-01.

So, you can get the date by:

```
datetime.date(1970, 1, 1) + datetime.timedelta(days=12784)
# datetime.date(2005, 1, 1)
```

Comment: But 1970,1,1 is not just an arbitrary origin for this dataset, it is the Unix time origin, so you could write `datetime.date(1970, 1, 1)` as `datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(0)` if you preferred - that is a datetime rather than a date but both will give the same when you then call `strftime`

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```py
>>> from datetime import date, timedelta
>>> (date(1970,1,1) + timedelta(days=12784)).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
'2005-01-01'
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case for a column in dataframe while using the accepted answer, you can use `.apply`:

```py
df["column"].apply(lambda x: (datetime.utcfromtimestamp(0) + timedelta(int(x))).strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
```

Comment: the question was not regarding dataframes